# Parse Error {} php Migrations

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting a parse error on `line 50` which is the closing brace for my schema create statement however I cannot see any missing syntax so I am confused.

**Code:**

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('user_id');
            $table->string('f_name');
            $table->string('l_name');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->date('dob');
            $table->string('company_name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->increments('landline');
            $table->increments('mobile');
            $table->increments('activated');
            $this->increments('social_login');
            $table->timestamp('last_login');
            $table->rememberToken();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {

        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: This line $this->increments('social_login'); should be $table->increments('social_login');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Schema::create(`

You never closed that `(`.

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('user_id');
        $table->string('f_name');
        $table->string('l_name');
        $table->string('gender');
        $table->date('dob');
        $table->string('company_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->increments('landline');
        $table->increments('mobile');
        $table->increments('activated');
        $this->increments('social_login');
        $table->timestamp('last_login');
        $table->rememberToken();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `increments` method incorrectly - Laravel will attempt to make an auto-incrementing primary key for each of the `$table->increments(...);` statements. Even the fields being specified would not suggest that an auto-incrementing field would be appropriate, you should check out the available methods [in the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations)